# How to get photos posted in location in google business

Tags: google-places-api, google-my-business-api

I have some projects to get all photos posted by users not by manager in the location business.
Is there any API google to do this actions?

Thanks you so much for your helping

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

We can create/update/retreive photos to your business using the latest mybusiness version v4. please find the below link https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media . Google created a new node for media in earlier versions this is embedded as part of location.

Comment: Hi, thanks you so much for your reply, using the API /accounts.locations.media, it returns only the photos uploaded by the manager (category COVER or ADDITIONAL) but not those of users . Is there any way to get all photos of users?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media
The result of this API does not including the photos of users, it returns only the manager's photos
May be I or parameter missing, but could you confirm me if it is the case or I have to add other parameters or something else

Thanks a lot for your reply